# How does unnest() treat NULL values and empty arrays?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, array, join

I am trying to achieve something like `LEFT JOIN` with array `unnest()` function. I want the query to return a row with a null value if the array is empty. Therefore, by using a `CASE` construct, I wanted to pass fake array with single null element if the source array is empty, but it does not work as expected:

Query 1

```
select element 
from (
  select array['a']::text[] as arr --< single non-null element
) sub, unnest(
  (
    case when array_length(sub.arr, 1) <= 0 then (array[null])::text[] 
    else sub.arr 
    end
  )
) element
-- returns 1 row with element = "a"
```

Query 2

```
select element 
from (
  select array[]::text[] as arr --< empty array
) sub, unnest(
  (
    case when array_length(sub.arr, 1) <= 0 then (array[null])::text[] 
    else sub.arr 
    end
  )
) element
-- returns 0 rows (should return 1 row with element = NULL?)
```

Query 3

```
select element 
from (
  select array[null]::text[] as arr --< single null element
) sub, unnest(
  (
    case when array_length(sub.arr, 1) <= 0 then (array[null])::text[] 
    else sub.arr 
    end
  )
) element
-- return single row with element = NULL
```

---

Just figured out that `select array_length(array[]::text[], 1)` returns `NULL` - my question is why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To quote [Tom Lane in the thread "Should array_length() Return NULL" on pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CADxJZo2bCXJwBDi8Zis7PmYnCbeLFbAjO7-N+=TVepUe4PeJRA@mail.gmail.com#CADxJZo2bCXJwBDi8Zis7PmYnCbeLFbAjO7-N+=TVepUe4PeJRA@mail.gmail.com):

> The thing is that that syntax creates an array of zero dimensions, not
> one that has 1 dimension and zero elements.  So "0" would be incorrect.

Hard to say whether `array_length()` should return `NULL` or `0` for an empty array dimension ...

#### Solution

You could ***invert the logic*** and process the original source array only if the length is `>= 1`:

```
WITH tbl(id, arr) AS (
   VALUES
     (1, '{a}'::text[])
   , (2, '{NULL}'::text[])
   , (3, '{}'::text[])
   , (4, '{x,y,z}'::text[])
   )
SELECT id, elem
FROM   tbl t
     , unnest (
          CASE WHEN array_length(t.arr, 1) >= 1
               THEN t.arr
               ELSE '{null}'::text[] END
       ) elem;
```

Returns at least one row for each source row.

Or, **much simpler**, use an ***actual `LEFT JOIN`*** (the comma in your `FROM` clause is short notation for `CROSS JOIN`):

```
SELECT id, elem
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.arr) elem ON true;
```

This fills in NULL values automatically for columns of the right table if no match is found. Exactly what you are trying to achieve.
Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=05989dd71f907c580b79688f57707a99)*